# Topological field without the Stone-Weierstrass property

Tags: general-topology, field-theory, weierstrass-approximation, topological-rings

Say that a (Hausdorff) topological field $\mathbb{F}$ (more generally, a topological ring) has the **Stone-Weierstrass property** if for all Hausdorff spaces $X$ every unital separating subalgebra $\mathcal{A}\subseteq C(X, \mathbb{F})$ with the property below is dense in $C(X, \mathbb{F})$ with compact-open topology.

> We have $\sigma\circ g\in \mathcal{A}$ for every $g\in\mathcal{A}$ and every field automorphism $\sigma:\mathbb{F}\to\mathbb{F}$ that is also a homeomorphism (automorphism in the category of topological fields).

Examples of fields with the SW property are $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, where in the latter case consideration of conjugation $z\mapsto \overline{z}$ is required for the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to be true (which justifies usage of field automorphisms in definition above).

More generally, any valuable field other than $\mathbb{C}$ satisfies the SW property with no field automorphisms necessary, see [The Stone-Weierstrass theorem for valuable fields](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-27/issue-2/The-Stone-Weierstrass-theorem-for-valuable-fields/pjm/1102983901.pdf) by Chernoff, Rasala and Waterhouse.

What's an example of a topological field without the SW property?

Comment: I would guess that a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ not closed under conjugation would not have the SW property, since to get the SW property you would morally need to be closed under conjugation; in particular, I would expect that polynomials are not dense in $C(\mathbb{F},\mathbb{F})$.  Proving it seems hard, though, since for such a field the compact-open topology on $C(\mathbb{F},\mathbb{F})$ is quite coarse.

Comment: (In the other direction, any subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ that is closed under conjugation does have the SW property, since you can easily reduce to the case of $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: Won't it be topology of uniform convergence if we restrict to some compact subset?

Comment: Right, but the problem is that the compact subsets of $\mathbb{F}$ are quite small in that case (in particular, they all have empty interior in $\mathbb{F}$).

Comment: In the definition we need to add the assumption that X is compact, no?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg In this phrasing of Stone-Weierstrass theorem compactness of $X$ isn't a requirement, this is because in the general case we use compact-open topology (think of uniform convergence on compact sets).

Comment: See for example theorem 3.3. in Dugundji's Topology